Map CTRL-i to TAB in X11 for Bluetooth Barcode Reader
I have a Bluetooth barcode scanner in HID mode (Keyboard Emulation) that reads barcode Code128. I want to embed a TAB in the code so it will send a value, then a TAB, and then more values. I was able to get the TAB in the barcode, but the scanner sends a "L-Control-i" key event. The xev output shows the "L_Control" then an 'i' instead of the TAB key. I understand that CTRL-i is also the same code as a TAB, but in this case, I want the TAB and not CTRL-i. Is there a way to map CTRL-i to TAB? I do not use CTRL-i anyway as a shortcut, so it would not bother me to override it. The second option is to change the barcode reader to Serial mode, but I am unsure how to map that to the keyboard input and if that would even work. I am using Rocky Linux 9. Do you have any other suggestions on how to get around this? Thanks!

TAB is Ctrl-I, see man ascii. The L_Control i X Window key sequence shows how your keyboard generates Ctrl-I for X Windows. Unless you are reading X events (difficult), by the time your program sees the key it's TAB, \011, 0x09, all the same.

I ended up finding this -https://github.com/philipl/evdevremapkeys
Since I do not need the KEY_GRAVE key, I remapped it as
KEY_TAB. That now works.
I know the CNTL-i is TAB in ascii, but that scanner sends key commands CNTL-i and not the code, so I had to just map a key I don't use. I actually had to use the because ~ is LEFTSHIFT+GRAVE key, but is in the Code128 so it worked.
